# In a 2 column grid, match multiple values from the first column, and add the associated values for each from the second column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, vlookup

Consider this set:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| YES | 1 |
| NO | 3 |
| NO | 3 |
| NO | 2 |
| NO | 5 |
| YES | 2 |
| YES | 1 |

I would like to create a formula that will choose all the values for "YES" from column 1, and for each match, add the values from column 2 (4).

I've attempted this using =SUM(VLOOKUP("YES",A1:B7, 2, FALSE)  But this only returns the number of the first value found.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"YES")
```

[image]

Comment: As usual, I tried to be fancy and missed the mark. Thank you for the response!